# Как вывести double в консоль?

Tags: c++, qt, строки, консоль, qt5

Имею код:

```
double db = 106352.518472222;
QString str = QString::number(db);
qDebug() << db << str;
```

Получаю в консоле:

```
106353 "106353"
```

Как вывести в консоль или перевести в строку оставив при этом значения после точки?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Для корректного преобразования в строку, нужно задать дополнительные параметры:

```
QString str = QString::number(db, 'f', 2);
```

`'f'` - означает, что результирующая строка должна содержать вещественное число в формате `X.X`, т.е. числа после запятой не должны быть отброшены.

`2` - диктует сколько чисел после запятой будет сохранено, в данном случае `2` цифры.

**Обновление:**

Почему `qDebug` отбрасывает числа после точки? Исследование показало, что внутри объекта `QDebug` используется `QTextStream`, у которого по умолчанию(в доке я этого не нашёл) `RealNumberNotation` выставлен в `QTextStream::SmartNotation`, в описании которого мы видим:

> Scientific or fixed-point notation, depending on which makes most
>   sense (printf()'s %g flag).

Это ровно то же самое, что по умолчанию используется для `double` и `float` в `QString::number()`, только мы не можем изменить поведение `qDebug`, т.к. доступа к внутреннему объекту `QTextStream` у нас нет.

**Обновление 2: Что означает флаг `%g` или почему мы получаем тот результат, что получаем.**

Согласно [документации](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)(которая совпадает с описанием в стандарте C11), мы имеем следующее:

- Пусть `P` - это точность, с которой должно быть отображено число.
- `X` - это степень 10-и, которая должна быть использована при конвертации числа в экспоненциальную форму отображения.
- Если `P` не задана, тогда по умолчанию принимается значение равное `6`, если `P` задана и равна `0`, тогда `P` принимается равной `1`.

Таким образом, имея `%g`(`'g'` в Qt) результирующий флаг `%f` или `%e` будет выбран в зависимости от следующих соображений: Если `P > X ≥ −4`, тогда используется `%f`, в противном случае используется `%e`. **ВАЖНО**: Если выбирается `%f`, то для него выставляется точность равная `P - X - 1`. Точность для `%f` это количество знаков после запятой, точность для `%g` это просто величина для формулы, которая сама по себе ничего не значит.

---

**Теперь давайте разберём почему наш пример вывел то, что вывел:**

Мы имеем число `106352.518472222`. По умолчанию `qDebug()` использует `'g'`(а значит подходит поведение `%g`). Значит мы имеем `P=6`(мы не задали точность, `qDebug` не позволяет этого сделать, а Qt сам по умолчанию задаёт `6`), `X=5`(если взять `X=6` то в записи не останется целой части, а это, видимо, не должно быть так, поэтому `X=5` это максимальное значение, которое может быть использовано в нашем числе). Подставляем в формулу: `P[6] > X[5] ≥ −4` - неравенство верное, а значит мы имеем случай с `%f`. Теперь посчитаем точность для `%f` - `P - X - 1 = 0`, а это значит, что должно быть `0` знаков после запятой. Поэтому выводится `106353`, округляя и отбрасывая всю дробную часть согласно заданной точности.

Давайте рассмотрим ещё пару примеров:

- `qDebug() << 1063521.518472222;` - `P=6`, `X=6`, `P[6] > X[6] ≥ −4` - неравенство не верно, а значит используем `%e`. Вывод: `1.06352e+06`
- `qDebug() << 10635.518472222;` - `P=6`, `X=4`, `P[6] > X[4] ≥ −4` - неравенство верное, а значит мы имеем случай с `%f`, с точностью `P - X - 1 = 1`. Вывод: `10635.5`

Таким образом, если разобраться, то поведение весьма определенное, но, на мой взгляд, вместо того, чтобы запоминать всё это, лучше отказаться от `'g'`(`%g`) и использовать `%f`/`%e` явно.

Comment: Интересно. А почему `qDebug() << db` не работает?

Comment: @VladD, добавил.

Comment: Ничего себе! Узнал что-то новое :) Спасибо!

Comment: Спасибо за помощь и потраченное время! Очень познавательно!

Comment: Всё равно не понятно, почему `%g` отбрасывает дробную часть. В документации сказано, что этот спецификатор выбирает лучшее между `%f` и `%e`, однако они оба ничего не отбрасывают - http://ideone.com/B6LyS8

Comment: А.. Всё. Понял. В документации сказано: `if P > X ≥ −4, the conversion is with style f or F and precision P − 1 − X.` `P` - precision (в нашем случае `6`), `X` - степень (в нашем случае `5`). @ixSci предлагаю дополнить Ваш ответ

Comment: @borisbn, а я вот нифига не понял. Читаю [ман](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf) и у меня дебит с кредитом не сходится. С одной стороны "where the number of digits after the decimal-point character is equal to the precision specification" и по умолчанию мы имеем `precision=6`, но это значение трактуется как **всего** цифр, а не цифр после запятой. Мне этот момент вообще не ясен.

Comment: @ixSci Я так понял, что для `%f` то что Вы пишете верно (д.б. 6 цифр после запятой), а для `%g` для точности берётся та хитрая формула, которую я взял отсюда http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf А то. что и там и там 6 цифр - совпадение

Comment: @borisbn, на свежую голову поизучаю вопрос и обновлю ответ, спасибо за наводку!

Comment: @borisbn, обновил пост.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать те же манипуляторы что использует QTextSTream. В данном случае подойдёт `fixed`

```
double db = 106352.518472222;
QString str = QString::number(db);
qDebug() << fixed << db << str;
```

Вывод:

```
106352.518472 "106353"
```

Чтобы изменить точность используется `qSetRealNumberPrecision`

```
double db = 106352.518472222;
QString str = QString::number(db);
qDebug() << qSetRealNumberPrecision(2) << fixed << db << str;
```

Вывод:

```
106352.52 "106353"
```

Answer (score 0):

[Документация](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#number-2) по выводу чисел с разными формата:

> `QString QString::number(double n, char format = 'g', int precision = 6)`
>
> Возвращает строковое представление числа `n`, отформатированное согласно переданному ключу формата и точности. Подробности смотрите в списке ключей.
>
> - ключ `e`: использовать формат `[-]9.9e[+|-]999`
> - ключ `E`: использовать формат `[-]9.9E[+|-]999`
> - ключ `f`: использовать формат `[-]9.9`
> - ключ `g`: использовать формат, как с ключами `e` или `f`, в зависимости от того, какой из них компактнее
> - ключ `G`: использовать формат, как с ключами `E` или `f`, в зависимости от того, какой из них компактнее

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать выдержку ответа здесь, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника. Ответы-ссылки могут стать недействительными в случае изменения страницы, на которую дана ссылка.

Comment: Пожалуйста, старайтесь нормально отформатировать скопированный текст, а не просто скопипастить. Советую ознакомиться с форматированием с помощью markdown, справка отображается при редактировании сообщения.

Comment: @fori1ton: Выдержку человек привёл :)

Comment: @VladD, формально - да. Фактически - копипаст английской документации на русскоязычном форуме без перевода - повод ещё раз предложить ответ к удалению как не соответствующий стандартам качества ресурса.

Comment: @fori1ton: В качестве аванса новому юзеру перевёл сам. В следующий раз буду минусовать.

Comment: Спасибо, след. раз будем оформлять как надою

Answer (score -1):

```
double db = 106352.518472222;
char str[16];
sprintf(str, "%f", db);
cout<<str<<endl;
```